# Dockerfile can't find my private ssh key

Tags: apache, ssh, docker

I'm trying to build a dockerfile so that it clones a private repo. I've believe I've added the right code to do this, but it keeps throwing this error:

```
build: id_rsa: no such file or directory
```

I've made sure the path is right and that the key is in there, and tried numerous other solutions proposed on here such as uncommenting the IdentityFile in ssh_config to no avail. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER John Fink <john.fink@gmail.com>
RUN apt-get update # Thu Nov  7 22:40:44 EST 2013


RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client mysql-server apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 pwgen      python-setuptools vim-tiny php5-mysql git

RUN easy_install supervisor

ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
ADD known_hosts /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN echo " IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

RUN cd /var/www
RUN git clone git@dev.ploonky.com:eric/hartshorn-portraiture.git

ADD ./start.sh /start.sh
ADD ./foreground.sh /etc/apache2/foreground.sh
ADD ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN chmod 755 /start.sh
RUN chmod 755 /etc/apache2/foreground.sh
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/start.sh"]
```

Comment: Do you know that the `/root/.ssh` directory exists before the `ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa` line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your `id_rsa` file in the current directory where your Dockerfile is? Try specifying the full path to it

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I thought "root" was referring to my computer's root, not the Dockerfile's. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did a more brute force version to see, and

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get -yq install ssh
ADD .ssh /root/.ssh/
CMD     bash
```

fails hard -

```
sven@mini:~/src/docker/tmp$ docker run -rm -t -i test 
root@810a2b43ed12:/# ls -la /root
total 20
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb 20 04:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 45 root root 4096 Feb 20 04:17 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Apr 19  2012 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  140 Apr 19  2012 .profile
drwx------  2 1000 1000 4096 Feb 20 04:04 .ssh
root@810a2b43ed12:/# ssh sven@192.168.1.220
Bad owner or permissions on /root/.ssh/config
root@810a2b43ed12:/# chown -R root:root /root/.ssh/
root@810a2b43ed12:/# ssh sven@192.168.1.220
Linux mini 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64
```

so I'd say you just need to do a

```
RUN chown -R root:root /root/.ssh
```

and you should be good to go.